# What event would capture Bootstrap alert .hide()

Tags: javascript, events, bootstrap-4, alerts

I can't figure out what event I could use to know when alert gets hidden by $('#alert').hide();
The only way to capture that is if I use .close().
But I really need to use .hide() and I need to know when that happens.

If using $(".alert").close() - $(".alert").on('closed.bs.alert') works fine but I need to use
$(".alert").hide('fast'); And BS doesn't expose event for that - what VJS event would do the job?

Comment: What triggers the hide?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution :)

```
    $(".alert").on("close.bs.alert", function () {
        // DO EVERYTHING YOU NEED
        $("#"+this.id).hide('fast');
        return false;
    });
```